# Translating IPv6 packets to IPv4 packets to reach a game server

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I am behind a DS-Lite system and therefore have no native IPv4 address.
But out of curiosity, I want to find out, if it is possible to set up a game server behind that. More precise, a counter-strike global offensive-server.

The problem: This game server only speaks IPv4 (welcome to the future VALVE).

Here is what I did so far:
I set up a portmapper via my Fritzbox and another third party-hoster (feste-ip.net).
By this combination I am now able to reach the server over IPv4. The third party-hoster then translates it into IPv6 packets, which are then sent to my Fritzbox, which then forwards these packages to my server.

The problem:
The server gets IPv6 packets, which cannot be handled by the CS GO-game server.
By searching the web I found out I need a 6in4-mapper. Is that correct? And if so, do I have to set this up on a different server, or can I do this on the server, where my game server is running on?

I'd be happy if you could tell me how to set up such a mapper on an Ubuntu-server.

Comment: Is that IPv4 address dedicated to you, or do you share it with other users?

Comment: I am pretty sure I share it with other users. I got an address like ServerName.feste-IP.net:77203. So the IP-adress is probably used by many other users and the assignment to my IPv6-address is done via the port-number.

Comment: That's one way to do it. It can also be done via hostname, but then it only works for protocols where the client sends a hostname. I have [a service](http://v4-frontend.netiter.com/) which does exactly that. But that's not going to help you either, because both services would require the server hosted on your LAN to listen on an IPv6 port.

Comment: Wow, that is good to know. I am always interested in cheaper alternatives. ;) But as you said, this does not solve my problem. The problem is more or less directly on my server. Which does listen on IPv6, but needs to give them to the running instance of the game server which can only listen on IPv4. At least, this is how I think it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking to do can be done using [NAT64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT64). Your scenario is a bit different from what NAT64 is usually used for. But that doesn't make it any less useful for you. Usually NAT64 is used together with DNS64, but you are not going to need DNS64 for your use case.

You cannot use a public NAT64, because you need the NAT64 to connect to an IPv4 address on your LAN. Thus you will need to host the NAT64 on your own LAN. A NAT64 usually need to be allocated a /96 IPv6 prefix. Assuming your ISP has routed a /48 or /56 to you (like they are supposed to), then you can easily allocate a /96 to a NAT64.

In such a setup it is important that you have a firewall between your internet connection and the NAT64. Without such a firewall outsiders could connect through your NAT64 to any IPv4 address reachable from your NAT64.

If the NAT64 does its own packet filtering, you probably have to disable that. The packet filtering you will need will be roughly the opposite of what is usually the case for a NAT64. You need to permit connections to a local IPv4 address and disallow connections to global IPv4 addresses.

One caveat to notice is, that the server will not know the IPv4 addresses of the clients. Thus logs from your server cannot be used to track down any abuse.

And in case NAT hole punching between clients is needed, the clients will need to use a different service for that, your server cannot assist them. However if the protocol only involves communication between client and server and no direct client to client communication, then this is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks, that looks lie a solution to my problem. I will try it out as soon as I am at home! I have never used a NAT64 before. I found a NAT64 tool called [TAYGA](http://www.litech.org/tayga) and if I understood this correct, it should be possible to install it on the same server where the game server instance is running and just route every IPv6-traffic onto my local IPv4 address, right?

Comment: @Chriz There are many different NAT64 implementations. Which of them will work for you is something I cannot answer. But I have heard people talk about TAYGA before, so it sounds like a reasonable implementation to try first. Running it on the same machine as the target server should work just fine. Just keep in mind that NAT64 implementations will expect to have a /96 routed to them, so you might need to add a routing table entry on the Fritzbox to route a /96 to the NAT64.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I marked your question as correct, as it is the basic setup needed to reach an IPv4-talking game server. BUT, for anyone who wants to do more specific stuff (as I did afterwards to reach my CS GO-server), you have to do a lot more adjustments of your specific game server, as only setting up a NAT64 is not sufficient. But to answer that questions, you have to look up in the forums of the game server developers (in my case VALVE, therefor the steam-community). Cheers